# Is there a function which satisfies the following conditions on monotonicity?

Tags: analysis

1. $f(x)$ is decreasing
2. $xf(x)$ is increasing
3. $xf(x)\cdot f(xf(x))$ is increasing

I know that the Beverton-Holt function, $f(x)=a/(1+bx)$ satisies 1) and 2) and satisfy 3).

I wish to know that under what condition on f which satisty (1) and (2) gives condition 3)

Comment: What is the motivation behind the third condition? Where does this question come from? What have you tried?

Comment: Doesn't condition 2 imply condition 3? Taking $g(x) := x f(x)$, condition 2 states that $g(x)$ is increasing and condition 3 states that $g(g(x))$ is increasing.

Comment: I want to know the condition on function such that the equation f(x)g(y)h(z)=1 satisfy for unique (x,y,z).

Comment: Your question seems to have changed several times. As for the question "I wish to know that under what condition on f which satisty (1) and (2) gives condition 3)", that is already answered in the affirmative by the comment above. Now you have this new question which seemingly has nothing to do with the original question in the post. Also, what are $f$, $g$, and $h$? Where do they come from? What has this condition got to do with monotonicity?